# CSS - float does not apply any effect

Tags: html, css, angular

I am have a list of messages, through which I loop and apply a style depending on a condition:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div *ngFor="let msg of allMessages" class="message">
    <div [ngClass]="(msg.sender === currentUID) ? 'me' : 'you'">
      <div>{{msg.sender}}</div>
      <div>{{msg.message}}</div>
      <div>{{msg.date | date:'HH:mm'}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wish all the messages which have the 'me' style to be on the right (`float:right;`) and all the 'you' style messages to be on the left side (`float:left;`). However, float does not seem to change the position of the elements.

```
.parent {
    position: relative; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1% !important;
    padding-left: 3% !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.me {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.you {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

Can anyone point to where my mistake is? As a css newbie a short explanation would help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another approach might be to use the `float` rule, combined with [the clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) technique to achieve the left/right alignment.

This can give you greater control over the horizontal width of the `message` `<div>` for instance, which might be useful for chat styled screen layouts.

To achieve this, try the following CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: relative; 
    /*display: flex;  Removed
    flex-direction: column; Removed*/
}

.message {
    /*display: flex; Removed*/
    padding: 1% !important;
    padding-left: 3% !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

/* Add this, known as "clearfix" */
.message:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.me {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.you {
    float: left; /*Update to left*/
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

/* Added as an optional extra to show how the width of .me,.you can be controlled */
.you, .me {
    width:25%;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly! One more question: What would be the possible style of `msg.date`'s <div> in order to position it at the bottom right corner of its parent?

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :-) Does this achieve what you want?

`.you div:last-child, .me div:last-child { text-align:right; }`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how important the use of `flex` is for your app on the whole, but you should be able to achieve this layout without `flex`.

If you're trying to achieve a chat history, with messages that appear on the left and right of the screen depending on who they are from, one approach might look like this:

```
.parent {
    position: relative; 
    /*display: flex;  Removed
    flex-direction: column; Removed*/
}

.message {
    /*display: flex; Removed*/
    padding: 1% !important;
    padding-left: 3% !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.me {
    /*float: right; Removed */
    text-align:right; /* Added */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.you {
    /*float: right;*/
    text-align:left; /* Added */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

Also, you can use `ngClass` in this way to make the behaviour of CSS class assignment more explicit:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'me' : (msg.sender === currentUID), 'you' : (msg.sender !== currentUID) }">
  <div>{{msg.sender}}</div>
  <div>{{msg.message}}</div>
  <div>{{msg.date | date:'HH:mm'}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I see. However, this still does not help me regarding the problem that `float: left;` and `float: right;` do not change the positions of the elements accordingly. I think this is a css problem, rather than html one.